# MySQL IFNULL CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a query in which I have a column of account numbers, which I've formatted by using a CONCAT statement to make the numbers 1-11111 instead of 11111.

There is a column with prior account numbers, however this value is NULL unless there is actually a prior account number. To try to only format the account numbers if they exist, I did this:

```
    IFNULL(CONCAT(LEFT(a.prior_acct, 1), '-', RIGHT(a.prior_acct, 5)), 0) AS prior_account
```

Now, this is properly formatting the account numbers that are there, into the 1-11111 format. However the NULL fields are returning with the hypen and not a 0 (equally acceptable would be a blank space).

I tried adding in an extra set of parenthesis around the full concat statement to see if that would take away the hyphen but no luck!

What am I missing? TIA!

Comment: your query is actually working on fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66a4a/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should work as it is unless you are actually storing empty string in `prior_acct` , not `NULL`.

```
SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT(LEFT('', 1),'-',RIGHT('', 5)),0); -- outputs -
SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT(LEFT(null, 1),'-',RIGHT(null, 5)),0); --outputs 0
```

It's not Oracle where empty string and `NULL` are the same. If you need to treat empty string as `null` , you need to specify it's explicitly. One way is

```
IFNULL(CONCAT(
IF(
  TRIM(LEFT('', 1))='',NULL, TRIM(LEFT('', 1))
  ),
 '-', RIGHT(a.prior_acct, 5)), 0) AS prior_account
```

Comment: That's what it was- the column was set to char instead of int and it was blank, not NULL. (another reason why I don't really like inheriting a database...)